# fixed sticky header expanding

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-position

I have the following issue. Trying to make a fixed header always on top. The page is responsive and when the screen is small the header if clicked expands pushing down the content... my issue is that I can't find the solution to make it work.. either I put position:fixed; and the header stays on top, but the content does not get pushed down... If position is relative the content gets pushed down but the header does not stick to the top. Is there any solution for this? Possibly with CSS only but if not also with javascript..

CSS:

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: inherit;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #f3f3f3;    
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #000;
}
```

javascript:

```
function showMobileBar(){
            $(menu).hide(0);
            $(showHideButton).show(0).click(function(){
                if($(menu).css("display") == "none")
                    $(menu).slideDown(settings.showSpeed);

                else
                    $(menu).slideUp(settings.hideSpeed).find(".dropdown, .megamenu").hide(settings.hideSpeed);
            });
        }

        // hide the bar to show/hide menu items on mobile
        function hideMobileBar(){
            $(menu).show(0);
            $(showHideButton).hide(0);
        }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
            <header id="menuzord" class="menuzord blue">
    <h1>
        <a href="/" class="menuzord-brand">
            <img src="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}" alt="logo"/>
        </a>
    </h1>
    <a href="/admin/"/>Admin</a>
    <ul class="menuzord-menu">
        <li class="active">
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a></li>
            {% endif %} -->
            <li class="active">
            </li>
            <li class="active">
            </li>
            <li class="active">
            </li>{% csrf_token %}
            <li class="active">
            </li>
    </ul>       
</header>
            <div class="container">
            <div class ="main">
                <div class="side">
                    <p>sidebar</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

thanks

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or provide a link? It's hard to tell how it's pushing it down, and what header.hidden is

Comment: .hidden is not important I should not insert that code because is not relevant to this question... http://www.webpulse.com.br/menuzord/index.html

Comment: seems you may need to use js approach to push it down

Comment: any suggestions how can I make this with js?

Comment: you just need to toggle `menuOpened` class on menu toggle(click) and add css mentioned in below answer

Comment: i tried your code but is still not pushing the content..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the link you provided has different code than you used. But to solve the issue in the link you provided, you will need to do several things.

CSS:

```
.nav {
    position: fixed;
}
.header {
    margin-top: 55px; /* the height of the fixed nav bar */
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .header {
        margin-top: 59px; /* the height of the fixed nav bar for smaller sizes */
    }
}
```

JavaScript: (updated the jQuery code that's on the site - the `$(".btMenu").click()` function)

```
$(".btMenu").click(function(){
    if($(".menu").children(".menuItem").css("display") == "none"){
        $(".menu").children(".menuItem").slideDown();
        var menuHeight = $(".menu").height(); // added - get the height of the menu after it has been expanded
        $(".header").animate({ marginTop: menuHeight + "px" }, 400); // animate the margin at the same speed of the slide, to match the new header height
    }
    else{
        $(".menu").children(".menuItem").slideUp();
        var menuHeight = $(".menu").height(); // added - get the height of the menu after it has been collapsed
        $(".header").animate({ marginTop: menuHeight + "px" }, 400); // animate the margin at the same speed of the slide, to match the new header height
    }
});
```

This does several things.

First, the CSS fixes the header to the top, and sets the margin of the header to match the height of the nav bar (they are different depending on the screen width).

Since JavaScript is what is opening the menu, you can simply calculate the new nav height (after the event of opening or closing the menu), and set the new margin (with the same animation speed) for the header. I haven't fully tested this, but this is the logic you'll need. If there is a delay, you may need to work with the animate and the slideDown a bit.

Comment: thanks.. you are correct my link was not the exact same example.. I edited the code now it reflects exactly my code.. can you please update your suggestion to this example? thanks

Comment: Are you not able to figure it out? I posted the solution here.

Comment: i still can't but your solution seems the right way, I'm trying it now... seems like I have to put $(".header").animate({ marginTop: -menuHeight + "px" }, 400); for the slideUp.. but still when the nav slides down the .header does not move and gets covered.. and when nav slidesUp the .header is pushed up if I use negative margin-top

Comment: Nowhere should there be a negative margin. There should be no dash before the menuHeight variable. Did you follow the complete logic of my code or are you confused why I did something? Don't just try to copy and paste, you won't learn that way...

Comment: Change from .nav in my code to be header in yours. Change .header in mine to be .container in yours. You may need to tweak a few things but I believe the main functionality will translate.

Comment: i changed that already... i could not manage to get it work beacause var menuHeight = $(".menuzord").height(); did not return the same height for slideUp and SlideDown... anyways the header will have a static height so I managed to make it work with $(".container").animate({ marginTop: 110 + "px" }, 400); and $(".container").animate({ marginTop: 15 + "px" }, 400);... this makes it slide up and down smoothly... thanks

Comment: Cool, glad you got it figured out. I said you would've had to change a couple things but figured you could do it with ease since it seemed you got your script from the example site you provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
.header.menuOpened{ 
 position: relative;
 top: 200px;
}
```

and when menu is opened add class `menuOpened` and remove when closed by js

```
$('.menu').click(function(){
      $('.header').toggleClass('menuOpened')
})
```

Comment: the content below the header still is not pushed down but the header expands over the content...

Comment: I can't insert links here but I use menuzord Responsive Megamenu plugin

Comment: webpulse.com.br/menuzord/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). Media queries can be used to define styles for different screen sizes. In this case you need to define your base style as a regular 'static' header.

Then when the screen width is greater than 600 you can apply a 'fixed' position to the header

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: #f3f3f3;    
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #000;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .header {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 999;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}
```